# Linq extension methods - how to get list of items that are equal to items in my collection?

Tags: linq, entity-framework, collections, ef-code-first, extension-methods

I have something like this:

```
public bool Function(IEnumerable<MyObject> MyObj)
{
    var context = new ContextDb();
    var MyObjFromContext = context.MyObjects.Where(obj => obj == MyObj) //that does not compile!
}
```

At commented section, i cannot do `obj == MyObj` comparison, because `obj` is a single item, and `MyObj` is a list of items.

So how can i obtain `MyObjFromContext` that is equal to `MyObj`, but comes from context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will probably have to query using the primary key:

```
var ids = MyObj.Select(o => o.Id).ToArray();
var MyObjFromContext = context.MyObjects.Where(obj => ids.Contains(obj.Id)).ToList()
```

Obviously this code assumes that your object has a "standard" integer primary key named `Id`

Comment: Yes, this seems more correct so I will delete my answer. 
Although from the variable name I guess you would use FirstOrDefault instead of ToList

Comment: Yes, that might work, i will mark it as accepted, but i don't like it much, isn't there any other way to do it in a single query without changing `MyObj`? I mean, in your example i need to do additional work, and create additional item, and that isn't "performance-friendly".

Comment: if you are working with detached objects, maybe you want to attach these objects instead (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectcontext.attach.aspx)?